# How to return ASC properly in query

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a set of rows in a database that have counts for something specific.
When I do my query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field ASC LIMIT 1
```

The results I get are incorrect, because it sorts based on the first number apparently.

So the results that are supposed to be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
10
```

End up being:

```
1
10
2
3
4
5
```

How can I adjust my query so that the field is returned in the proper order? I'm not sure how to word it to search to get the proper answer.

Comment: What is the type of column?

Comment: How did you get 6 values(rows) with `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: `order by cast(field as int)`

Comment: Make sure it is int or a number depending upon your db because the kind of data you have above needs to be in a column of type int

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick I learned long time ago that works on even strings of alphabet as well which is.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY LENGTH(field) ASC, field ASC
```

learn this trick and you're now a master of `ORDER BY` :D

Comment: you got my vote! Works perfectly.